# Error assigning permission to Keyvault terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

Not sure why this is happening but I get error for the below definition:

> Error: checking for presence of existing Secret
> "auditmeta-storage-account-key" (Key Vault
> "https://abckv.vault.azure.net/"): keyvault.BaseClient#GetSecret:
> Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error:
> autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden"
> Message="The user, group or application
> 'appid=2406-df1c-44b0-a89d-xxxx;oid=9xxxx02-5xx9-404a-axxe-exxxf;numgroups=4;iss=https://sts.windows.net/a9x-36xx-4xx7-a9dc-30xxxx3/'
> does not have secrets get permission on key vault
> 'abckv;location=eastus'. For help resolving this issue, please see
> [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287%22)
> InnerError={"code":"AccessDenied"}

Terraform definition:

```
   resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "keyvault_role" {
  scope                = azurerm_key_vault.vault.id
  role_definition_name = "Key Vault Administrator"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "storage_account_key" {
  name         = "auditmeta-storage-account-key"
  value        = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.primary_access_key
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.vault.id

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
    service     = var.service
    team        = var.team
  }
}
```

What wrong am i doing here? I am basically trying to store primary access key of a storage account in one of the keyvault I defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Key message "The user, group or application ... **does not have secrets get permission on key vault**

You must give the **secrets get permission on your key vault**

With a Block like this, it should work:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.vault.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get",
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the given answer below, just to help someone who is looking for adding secret to keyvault using RBAC the above answer will not work as you can either have access policies or access control. Terraform ends up throwing error "checking for presence of existing Secret" However I was able to get it working using azapi

```
resource "azapi_resource" "sftpsecret" {
  type = "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2022-07-01"
  name = "sftpsecret1"
  parent_id = module.kv_adf.id
 
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
   
      value = "string"
    }
  })
}
```

This way i was able to create a secret